# How to configure SELinux to allow apache to run git

Tags: centos, httpd, selinux

I have a CentOS 6 server and I'm trying to get the apache web server to run `git pull` in a directory.

The php file is simply:

```
<?php
    shellexec('cd /var/www/vhosts/domain;git pull');
```

However, the `git pull` command is not run when the file is requested via a browser.

Temporarily turning off SELinux by running `setenforce 0` allows it to run, but this is not a safe solution.

/var/log/audit shows the following error when the file is requested.

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1401182476.567:363184): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=11082 comm="ssh" name="known_hosts" dev=dm-0 ino=11272197 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your system temporarily wit SELinux in Permissive mode (setenforce 0). Carry out your normal operations so that errors are logged to audit.log.

You can then use [audit2why](http://linux.die.net/man/8/audit2why) to get an explanation of the issue(s). You can use [audit2allow](http://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow) to generate a loadable policy module. So for example

```
audit2allow <wyred.log
type=AVC msg=audit(1401182476.567:363184): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=11082 comm="ssh" name="known_hosts" dev=dm-0 ino=11272197 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file

    Was caused by:
            Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

            You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this 
            access.
```

then

```
audit2allow -M wyred <wyred.log
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i wyred.pp
```

will generate a .pp file and a readable.te file.