# SELinux problems running Expect script from fail2ban

Tags: selinux, fail2ban, expect

I have an Expect script that works fine if I run it manually, but fails when run as an action from Fail2ban. The error message is as follows:

```
spawn /usr/bin/telnet 192.168.242.1
The system has no more ptys.  Ask your system administrator to create more.
    while executing
"spawn /usr/bin/telnet $hostname"
```

With the corresponding message in audit.log:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1407894085.867:54862): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=14748 comm="ciscoacl.exp" name="ptmx" dev=devtmpfs ino=5288 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:fail2ban_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ptmx_t:s0 tclass=chr_file
```

The script is running as root (confirmed by running `whoami` from the script) so I expected not to have any issues. What, if anything, can I do to fix this? (No, I don't want to disable SELinux!)

I don't think the script itself makes a difference here, but I can post it if needed.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/598763/how-to-configure-selinux-to-allow-apache-to-run-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make a custom policy with audit2allow to allow fail2ban to read write to chr_file. Probably it will look like this:

```
require {
        type ptmx_t;
        type fail2ban_t;
        class chr_file { read write };
}

#============= fail2ban_t ==============
allow fail2ban_t ptmx_t:chr_file { read write };
```

Are you sure there are no more denies?

Comment: You're right; I checked and found a couple of other deny entries. Changed your rule to `{ read write ioctl open }` and am waiting for the next script kiddie to test against! Will accept if it works, or update info otherwise.

Comment: Setting up our new NOC, had the same error, searched it out, this was the first result. Thanks again 8 years later!